# Feedback to achieve four column to column list using flex - Round 2

Tags: image, flexbox, hyperlink, accessibility, html-lists

I'm having trouble achieving a responsive flex layout to house an unordered list. Each list item needs to contain an image on top of a link. I'd like it to be four columns at desktop, laptop and tablet sizes then break to two columns at mobile. Another stack overflow user helped me clean up my code but when I replaced the paragraph elements with links (which I need to use), it broke the evenly spaced four to two column layout.

I need to use a unordered list for accessibility purposes as this will eventually hold a list of images, plus it's respective link.

Here's where I'm at right now:

https://codepen.io/shannon-hart82/pen/QWvgpdz

```
<style>
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  
}

.headline {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul.flex-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  width: calc((200px + 2 * 10px)*2);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

ul.flex-list img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

li.flex-list-item {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
 width: 100%;
  
}


@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
    ul.flex-list {
        width: calc((200px + 2 * 10px)*4);
    }
}
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="headline">
          <h2 >Best fruit</h2>
          <p>Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
      </div>

      <ul class="flex-list">
        <li class="flex-list-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />
          <a href="/">Apples</a>
        </li>

        <li class="flex-list-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

          <a href="/">Oranges</a>
        </li>

        <li class="flex-list-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

          <a href="/">Strawberries</a>
        </li>

        <li class="flex-list-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

          <a href="/">Blueberries</a>
        </li>

        <li class="flex-list-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

          <a href="/">Nectarines</a>
        </li>

        <li class="flex-list-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

          <a href="/">Bananas</a>
        </li>

        <li class="flex-list-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

          <a href="/">Rasberries</a>
        </li>

        <li class="flex-list-item">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

          <a href="/">Blackberries</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you use flexbox this way, the number of items displayed per row is going to depend on the width of your child-items and the width of the parent-container. If you reduce your width of the images from 200px to 160px, it will stack 4 wide. If you need the images to stay 200px wide, you can try adjusting the width  or padding on the list-item elements.

Answer (score 0):

**Set a fixed `min-width` and `flex-basis` to control the number of flex items in each flex line (row)**.

Overall, this would be the easiest to achieve using [CSS grid layout](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout). But the question specifically asked for a flexbox solution, so I’ll answer that.

The current solution isn’t working because the size of your image (160 px) affects the minimum size of your flex items. That happens because your flex items have the default `min-width: auto`, and for flex items that means they will try to at least fit their content, including the image. That minimum size then affects how many flex items go into each flex line.

So to get an exact number of items in each flex line, you need these two things:

- set `min-width: 0` on your flex items so they stop looking at their content (the image) to determine their minimum size
- set `flex-basis` to a percentage of the flex container corresponding to the number of columns you want. If you want 2 columns, each item should have `flex-basis: 50%`. For 4 columns, that would be `flex-basis: 25%`
- set `box-sizing: border-box` to make sure any `border` and `padding` you set on your flex items is included in that `flex-basis` percentage. Otherwise, your flex items will grow bigger than the percentage you want, and that will again mess up the number of columns you get.

Below is a working solution to your problem. I used a [CSS custom property](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) to make calculating the `flex-basis` easier, but you can also just put the percentage in there.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  border: 2px dotted black;
  display: block;
}

.headline {
  border: 2px dotted green;
  text-align: center;
}

ul.flex-list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  width: calc((160px + 2 * 10px) * 2);
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.flex-list img {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
}

li.flex-list-item {
  --number-of-columns: 2;
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 0;
  flex: 1 1 calc(100% / var(--number-of-columns));
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  border: 2px dotted red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 991px) {
  ul.flex-list {
    width: calc((200px + 2 * 10px) * 4);
  }

  li.flex-list-item {
    --number-of-columns: 4;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="headline">
    <h2>Best fruit</h2>
    <p>Consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
  </div>

  <ul class="flex-list">
    <li class="flex-list-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />
      <a href="/">Apples</a>
    </li>

    <li class="flex-list-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

      <a href="/">Oranges</a>
    </li>

    <li class="flex-list-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

      <a href="/">Strawberries</a>
    </li>

    <li class="flex-list-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

      <a href="/">Blueberries</a>
    </li>

    <li class="flex-list-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

      <a href="/">Nectarines</a>
    </li>

    <li class="flex-list-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

      <a href="/">Bananas</a>
    </li>

    <li class="flex-list-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

      <a href="/">Rasberries</a>
    </li>

    <li class="flex-list-item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="" />

      <a href="/">Blackberries</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```